How to fix only one header of two React Native flat lists
I'm using React Native and using the FlatList component.
The problems we are trying to solve are:
There is a header in FlatList, and the header is bounded by two elements. (TopArea, CategorySelectBar)
Here, when scrolling down, I want to stick only the CategorySelectBar to the top of the screen, but stickyHeaderIndices makes both elements stick. Is there a way to fix this?
It's okay to change the HTML structure.
thank you
enter image description here
<StyleHome>
      <Header
        pageName={route.name}
        setIsLanguageSheetOpen={setIsLanguageSheetOpen}
        isShouldChangeHeaderColor={isShouldChangeHeaderColor}
      />

      <FlatList
        onScroll={scrollHandler}
        data={storeInfo.menu_info}
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces={false}
        ListHeaderComponent={() => (
          <>
            <StyleTopArea>
              <StyleStoreName>{storeInfo?.store_info.name}</StyleStoreName>
            </StyleTopArea>
            <CategorySelectBar
              storeInfo={storeInfo}
              currentCategory={currentCategory}
              setCurrentCaetegory={setCurrentCaetegory}
            />
          </>
        )}
        renderItem={({item: menuInfo, index}) => (
          <StyleMenuList key={menuInfo._id.$oid}>
            {index !== 0 && (
              <StyleText
                fontSize={16}
                style={{fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 20, marginTop: 20}}>
                {menuInfo.Name}
              </StyleText>
            )}
            {menuInfo.MenuInfo.map((menu, i) => (
              <MenuListItem
                navigation={navigation}
                key={menu._id.$oid}
                menu={menu}
                index={i}
              />
            ))}
          </StyleMenuList>
        )}
      />

      {isLanguageSheetOpen && (
        <LanguageChangeBottomSheet
          setIsLanguageSheetOpen={setIsLanguageSheetOpen}
        />
      )}
    </StyleHome>

I'm just starting out with React Native, so I might be a little new to the concepts, but I'd appreciate any help.
**I have the following opinions:

The View component does not seem to be position sticky.
Among TopArea and CategorySelector, I hope that only TopArea disappears from the screen when scrolling.**


<StyleHome>
  <Header
    pageName={route.name}
    setIsLanguageSheetOpen={setIsLanguageSheetOpen}
    isShouldChangeHeaderColor={isShouldChangeHeaderColor}
  />

  <StyleTopArea>
    <StyleStoreName>{storeInfo?.store_info.name}</StyleStoreName>
  </StyleTopArea>

  <CategorySelectBar
    storeInfo={storeInfo}
    currentCategory={currentCategory}
    setCurrentCategory={setCurrentCategory}
    style={{position: 'sticky', top: 0, zIndex: 1}}
  />

  <FlatList
    onScroll={scrollHandler}
    data={storeInfo.menu_info}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    bounces={false}
    ListHeaderComponent={() => <></>} // Empty component since the header is rendered above
    renderItem={({ item: menuInfo, index }) => (
      <StyleMenuList key={menuInfo._id.$oid}>
        {index !== 0 && (
          <StyleText
            fontSize={16}
            style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', marginBottom: 20, marginTop: 20 }}>
            {menuInfo.Name}
          </StyleText>
        )}
        {menuInfo.MenuInfo.map((menu, i) => (
          <MenuListItem
            navigation={navigation}
            key={menu._id.$oid}
            menu={menu}
            index={i}
          />
        ))}
      </StyleMenuList>
    )}
  />

  {isLanguageSheetOpen && (
    <LanguageChangeBottomSheet
      setIsLanguageSheetOpen={setIsLanguageSheetOpen}
    />
  )}
</StyleHome>

Try this One

First of all, thank you so much for your reply. I tried it, but it seems to have failed for the following reasons.

The View component does not seem to be position sticky.
Among TopArea and CategorySelector, I hope that only TopArea disappears from the screen when scrolling.

